# Upgraded to Office 2013, now VBScript will not open an email from Access 2003

Tags: vbscript

I have a client uses Access 2003 for a database. Inside the database, there is a "quick email" command (button).  They were using Office 2010, and it worked.  I have moved them to an Office 2013 environment, all Office programs are 32-bit, and the 'quick email' will no longer work.    I get:

Run-time error '429':

ActiveX component can't created object

I click the debug button, and it shows the following vbscript:

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Public Enum MailingType
    Individuals = 0
    Companies = 1
End Enum

Public Sub SendEmail(Optional mailto As String, Optional mailcc As String,     
Optional mailbcc As String, Optional mailSubject As String, Optional 
mailBody As String, Optional mailSend As Boolean)

        Dim myOutlook As Object 'Outlook.Application
        Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")   <-( yellow)
        Dim myEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
        Set myEmail = myOutlook.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

    Dim ns As Object 'Outlook.NameSpace
    Set ns = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim f As Object 'MAPIFolder
    Set f = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'olFolderInbox

'   Dim e As Object 'Outlook.Explorer
'   Set e = myOutlook.Explorers.Add(F)
'   e.Activate

    With myEmail

        If mailto <> "" Then .To = mailto
        If mailcc <> "" Then .cc = mailcc
        If mailbcc <> "" Then .bcc = mailbcc
        If mailSubject <> "" Then
            .subject = mailSubject
        Else
            .subject = "From ABC"
        End If
        If mailBody <> "" Then .body = mailBody

        .display

       ' If mailSend Then .send

    End With
    Set myEmail = Nothing
    Set myOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have a feeling the script for this to work in Outlook 2013 and 2010 is different.  This works in 2010, but not 2013.  If anyone could help with this, that would be great!

Thanks everyone for taking a peek!
Jeffrey

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with another Access application attempting to open an instance of Outlook 2013 to send an email.  The error 429 only occurred when Outlook was already open.  In our situation, we found one solution was to either close Outlook prior to running the VBA code or make sure that Outlook was launched as an administrator prior to running the "send" from within VBA.